# Where can I get a replacement transmitter for my wireless mouse

Tags: wireless-mouse

I have Logitech V450 wireless mouse and I seem to have misplaced the tiny little USB transmitter it uses to communicate with the computer.

Where can I get a replacement transmitter?

Once I get a replacement will I have to do anything special to pair the new transmitter and the mouse?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but it's not a transmitter, it's a [transceiver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transceiver).

Answer (score 1):

If the unit is discontinued by Logitech, you could try Amazon.com to see if they have the exact set - maybe at a lower price.  That way you have a spare mouse too.

Usually, the set up is easy - plug in the transmitter - hit the connect button on the transmitter - lights flash - hit the connect button on the mouse - voila!

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around I found the mouse on Logitech's site, followed the support link and found [the part](http://www.buylogitech.com/DRHM/servlet/ControllerServlet?Action=DisplayProductSearchResultsPage&SiteID=logius&Locale=en_US&CallingPageID=ProductSearchResultsPage&keywords=831878). Its $10, plus another $6 for shipping (in the US).

It's almost not worth it. I'll have to see what the current lineup of bluetooth mice looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to gently ask the Logitech support. I have good experience of it : I got free replacement "feet" for one mouse, and they replaced my malfunctioning mx1000 without problem (they actually sent a new one, without me sending back the previous).

So you can always try, maybe they will redirect you to the page you found, to buy a new one, but maybe they will send you one for free, you never know, it's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, calling Logitech should be the first recourse. I've had nothing but great experiences from contacting their customer support.